# Where to import child route in standalone components

Tags: angular, router, angular-standalone-components

I'm trying to create a page that has 2 different route.

I'm trying to import the `RouterModule` in my standalone component, but do get

> Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[] | Type'.

My code

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'first',
    loadComponent: () => import('./first/first.component').then((m) => m.FirstComponent),
  },
  {
    path: 'second',
    loadComponent: () => import('./second/second.component').then((m) => m.SecondComponent),
  },
]

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,

    // Router
    RouterModule.forChild(routes), // Error > Type 'ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule>' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[] | Type<any>'.
  ],
  template: `<p>home works!</p>`,
  styleUrl: './home.component.css',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class HomeComponent {}
```

Does somebody have an Idea ?

### Note

This is a `.forChild()` as HomeComponent is being imported inside `app.module.ts` which have the `.forRoot()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understand we **cannot use the `RouterModule.forChild()`** in a standalone component.

Therefore we need to import it when we initialise our project.
*I keep it in my `app-routing.ts` file for "separation of concerne" purpose.*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent: () => import('./home/home.component').then((m) => m.HomeComponent),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'first',
        loadComponent: () => import('./home/first/first.component').then((m) => m.FirstComponent),
      },
      {
        path: 'second',
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('./home/second/second.component').then((m) => m.SecondComponent),
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'first',
      },
    ],
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Then you import it in your `app.component.ts` file.

*thx [sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709348/sam-scholefield) for your help*

Answer (score 3):

Import RouterModule once at the top level and then lazy load any child routes as required:

```js
// app.routes.ts (main routing document)

export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: APP_PATHS.FEATURE.AUTH,
    },
    // AUTH
    {
        path: APP_PATHS.FEATURE.AUTH,
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./features/auth/auth.routes').then(
                (mod) => mod.AUTH_ROUTES
            ),
    },

// auth.routes.ts

export const AUTH_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: SplashComponent,
    },
    {
        path: APP_PATHS.SECTION.LOGIN,
        component: LoginComponent,
    },
    {
        path: APP_PATHS.SECTION.FORGOT_PASSWORD,
        component: ForgotPasswordComponent,
    },
    {
        path: APP_PATHS.SECTION.REGISTER,
        component: RegisterComponent,
    },
];
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand 100%, but would pretty much call the route in my home component and not globally, as for what I see, this wouldn't enable lazy load after all. And my problem is by the `import` of the `RouterModule.forChild()` one, can you also add this part please ?

Comment: As stated I do not understand why you are importing RouterModule.forChild(), however from your example it is difficult to determine your desired behaviour.

I assume you want something like: `../home/first` - please provide example URL's and I will rework my answer to be more precise. Also, to truly embrace standalone you should drop `app.module.ts` and begin using `bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, APP_CONFIG)` in `main.ts` :)

Comment: Thx Sam, as I come from the module way, I was used to declare the route in children pages. As I see, standalone component routes should be declared at the start of the application, which I did and then it worked. therefore I assume that `.forChild()` isn't working anymore. Thx for your help though, I'll add a response to explain where the error was.

Answer (score 0):

You where fairly close

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'first',
    loadComponent: () => import('./first/first.component').then((m) => m.FirstComponent),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child',
        loadComponent: () => import('./child/child.component').then((m) => m.ChildComponent),
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'second',
    loadComponent: () => import('./second/second.component').then((m) => m.SecondComponent),
    loadChildren: () => import('./lazy-children/lazy-children.routes')
  },
]
```

Comment: Hi and thx for your help.
I tried it, but same error, this is not working :/ I do also not understand what you've changed and why it should fix my error '^^Can you please explain a little bit more?